# TypeScript Error: 'Highlight' cannot be used as a JSX component after deleting yarn.lock and re-installing node_modules

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, types, eslint

I encountered a TypeScript error in my Next.js project, which is part of a monorepo. The error message reads as follows:

```
Type error: 'Highlight' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its instance type 'Highlight' is not a valid JSX element.
    The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
      Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/@types/react-router/node_modules/@types/react/ts5.0/index").ReactNode'.
        Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
```

This issue occurred right after I deleted the **yarn.lock** file and re-installed the **node_modules** using the yarn install command. My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^17.0.21",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4",
    ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    ...
  },
  "resolutions": {}
}
```

Even when I try to solve this problem by deleting the file and running yarn build again, other errors appear, such as:

```
Type error: Type '"true"' is not assignable to type '"" | "anonymous" | "use-credentials"'.
<link
    rel="preconnect"
    href={`https://${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ALGOLIA_APP_ID}-dsn.algolia.net`}
    crossOrigin="true"
        ^
/>
```

One of the initial solutions I tried was adding the @types packages to the resolutions field in the package.json file. However, this did not resolve the TypeScript error.

I'm currently stuck with this TypeScript error, and none of the solutions I've tried so far have worked. I would appreciate any help or suggestions to resolve this issue. If you need any additional information or code snippets, please let me know. Thank you in advance for your help!